# How to send a file data to controller method with angularjs?

Tags: c#, html, angularjs, asp.net-core-mvc

My project is Asp.net MVC Core.

I try to upload a file with angularjs to mvc controller but i make some mistakes; sending value is null in method. I can write a console log , actually data is not null but problem is sending to the controller.

```js
angular.module("myApp").controller("myVm", function ($scope, $http, $window) {
    var vm = $scope;
    var url = "UploadSingle";
    var config = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": undefined,
        }
    };
    vm.upload = function () {

        var formData = new $window.FormData();
        formData.append("file-0", vm.files[0]);
        console.dir(formData);

        $http.post(url, formData, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: new HttpHeaders().set('enctype', 'multipart/form-data')
        }).
            then(function (response) {
                vm.result = "SUCCESS";
                vm.data = response.data.data;
            }).catch(function (response) {
                vm.result = "ERROR " + response.status;
            });
    };
```

```
       public async Task<JsonResult> UploadSingle(IFormFile formData) 
       {
           using (var reader = new StreamReader(formData.OpenReadStream())) 
           {
                var fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                var parsedContentDisposition = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(formData.ContentDisposition);
                var fileName = parsedContentDisposition.FileName;

            }
            return Json(new { result = "Test" });
    }
```

Comment: `formData.append("file-0", vm.files[0], "file-o.jpg");`   **formData.append** requires three parameters for file.  [See here for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)

Comment: When posting data using the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), it is important to set the content type to `undefined`.

Comment: What is `headers: new HttpHeaders().set('enctype', 'multipart/form-data')`?? That looks like Angular 2+ code.

Comment: There is no `enctype` header. You need `Content-Type` here.

Comment: Try to keep the same name between `formData.append("file-0", vm.files[0]);` and `IFormFile formData`. change to `formData.append("formData", vm.files[0]);`